# Placement New in Swift

Tags: swift, memory-management, shared-memory

Is there a way to control the address an object will be allocated at in Swift? I know Objective-C has this feature (although it's hidden away in the runtime), and C++ has placement new, but I don't see a way to do it in pure Swift.

Although the `UnsafeMutablePointer` type may be used to store arbitary objects (using it's `initialize...` methods), those methods require that the source object already exists, which requires an extra memory allocation and copy.

I've used this technique for doing IPC with memory-mapped files before, but I'd like to write some of my newer side-projects in Swift...

Comment: This could be what you are looking for: [Secure Memory For Swift Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27715985/secure-memory-for-swift-objects)

Comment: That looks really close, but the `UnsafeMutablePointer<Memory>.initialize...()` functions seem to require that the objects they're being initialized with already exist somewhere. I'd like to avoid the extra allocation and copy if possible.

Comment: You could write only this specific feature in ObjC and the rest in Swift.